# How to insert array into a column in spanner database using javascript es6

Tags: javascript, node.js, object, ecmascript-6, google-cloud-spanner

I have the following data:

```
data = {
    id: 10012,
    name: "abc",
    hobby: ["cricket", "football"]
}
```

My table structure is:
**id int64,
name string(25),
petName string(20),
hobby string(25)**

How to insert an array of data into the spanner table?

```
async insert(data) {
    const result;
    const params = {
        id: data.id,
        name: data.name,
        petName: null
    }
    await data.hobby.map(async h => {
        params.hobby = h;
        const query = 'INSERT INTO my_table (id, name, petName, hobby) VALUES (@id, @name, @petName, @hobby)';
        result = await db.RunTrans(query, params);
    });
    return result;
}
```

The above code doesn't insert the values into the table. Kindly help me with this..

Comment: does this code gives error ? The query should probably be in a string; ie. `query = "INSERT INTO..."`

Comment: Using async/await can give unexpected results. Return the promise and consume it with .then() instead.

Comment: @lipsumar it was a string. sorry, I forgot to put in the question. I updated the question..

Comment: `paramas` is used instead of `params`. `query` holds a syntax error. Please fix these first

Comment: @briosheje I forgot to put it in the question. I just updated the question..

Comment: I quess 'insert' is a function? You forgot to async 'function' insert(data) {

Comment: @OscarR I'm using it inside a class..

Comment: `result` is a const. however you assign values to it inside your map function. (and you assign values over and over, so even if it was a let you'll only get the last value)

Answer (score 2):

Destructure out the wanted values (to avoid unnecessary repeated dot notation) then use template literals:

```
async insert(data) {
    const result;
    const params = {
        id: data.id,
        name: data.name,
        petName: null
    }
    await data.hobby.map(async h => {
        params.hobby = h;
        const { id, name, petName, hobby } = params;
        const query = `INSERT INTO my_table (id, name, petName, hobby) VALUES (${id}, ${name}, ${petName}, ${hobby})`;
        result = await db.RunTrans(query, params);
    });
    return result;
}
```

Comment: It is not improving bro. I get the result same as to my code's result..

Answer (score 1):

You aren't handling any promise issues, so it is possible a few different things.

1. I am not certain your columns are nullable. If they aren't petName being NULL isn't valid for the schema.
2. @google-cloud/spanner doesn't have a `RunTrans` method. it has a `runTransaction` and a `runTransactionAsync` method though.
3. The way this is authored, the code would result in multiple rows with the same id. Typically id would be set to a primary key. Since I assume this isn't in error, I made a primary key that is the composite of hobby and id as this would be unique.

The documentation for runTransactionAsync is here:
https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/spanner/3.1.x/Database.html#runTransactionAsync

```
const {Spanner} = require('@google-cloud/spanner');

const spanner = new Spanner();

const instance = spanner.instance('testinstance');
const db = instance.database('people');

async function insert(data) {
    const params = {
        id: data.id,
        name: data.name,
        petName: null
    }

    const query = 'INSERT INTO my_table (id, name, petName, hobby) VALUES (@id, @name, @petName, @hobby)';
    await Promise.all(data.hobby.map(async h => {
        await db.runTransactionAsync(async (transaction) => {
            params.hobby = h;
            await transaction.run({
                sql: query,
                params: params,
                types: {
                    petName: {
                        type: 'string'
                    }, 
                }
            });
            await transaction.commit();
        });
    }));
};

insert({id: 0, name: 'foo', hobby:['a','b','c'], extra: 'blah'}).catch((r) => console.log(r))
```